# Why am i getting a "Your code did not execute within the time limits" on hacker rank?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
static BigInteger handshake(int n) {

    BigInteger fact = BigInteger.ONE;
    int res = n-1;

    for(int i= res ; i>0 ;i--)
    {  
       fact=fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }

    if(res==0){return BigInteger.ZERO;}
    else{
       return fact;
    }
}
```

This is the factorial function that I have created. I have used the `BigInteger` class so it can store larger integers.

Comment: Can you share a link to the question?

Comment: BigInteger is very slow to work with. Are you sure that Long is out of range for the expected result? You could try to start with long multiplication and if the expected result would overflow, switch to BigInteger, so half or your algorithm would execute faster.

Comment: @Simulant thnx ill try that.

Comment: @Mureinik here u go: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/handshake/problem

Comment: @Simulant i tried long long but no luck .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to speed up the calculation of factorial by an order of magnitude (although there are a few interesting ideas in the comments). The good news is that that's probably not the problem here - your algorithm is incorrect.

`n!` is the number of ways you can sort `n` elements, but the problem here is much simpler. Given `n` people, each person shakes hands with all the others - i.e., `n-1` other people. We then divide that in half, since Alice shaking Bob's hand is exactly the same as Bob shaking Alice's hand. So, to make a long story short, you don't need to find the factorial of `n`. And since `n * (n-1)/2` is well within the limits of `long` for the given input range, you don't have to muck around with `BigInteger`s either:

```java
private static long handshake(long n) {
    return n * (n - 1L) / 2L;
}
```